# Integrate QTP tests with TFS 2010

Tags: testing, tfs, continuous-integration, qtp

Has anyone done work to integrate tests created using QTP (keyword driven automation) with Team Foundation Server 2010 (or even with 2008)?

Our Organization is planning to implement TFS 2010 as the tool of choice for all Engineering related work, but the Test Framework we currently are using is developed using QTP. If I now create a build with TFB and wish to execute a continuous integration process for checkin-build-test, is there any way in which I can implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a blog post that shows how to use the QuickTestPro COM automation (`QuickTest.Application`) to invoke the tests from a MSBuild script: http://web.archive.org/web/20080614153438/http://dotnet.org.za/cjlotz/archive/2007/09/17/part-7-continuous-integration-the-qtpbuild.aspx

Once you have the script created and the right pre-req's installed, it looks like it's as easy as this:

```
<Exec Command="cscript.exe /nologo $(DOUBLE_QUOTES)$(QtpTestCasesFolder)\$(CCNetProject).TestCases.txt$(DOUBLE_QUOTES) $(DOUBLE_QUOTES)$(QtpOutputFolder)$(DOUBLE_QUOTES) $(DOUBLE_QUOTES)$(QtpOutputFolder)\$(QtpResultsSummaryFile)$(DOUBLE_QUOTES) $(DOUBLE_QUOTES)$(QCServer)$(DOUBLE_QUOTES) $(QCUser) $(QCPassword)" ContinueOnError="true">
    <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" ItemName="QtpExitCode"/>
</Exec>
```